# How can I get name of month after the current month?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

The following gives me `October`

```
 echo date('F');
```

I'm using the following code to give me the name of the coming month (the month after this one), so I'm hoping to see `November`.

```
$nextmonth = date("F",strtotime("+1 months"));
```

Today is 31st Oct, but the above gives 'December' What am I doing wrong? How can I get the month after the current month?

Comment: there is no 31.11 so you get December

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use relative formats to get the first day of the next month:

```
echo (new DateTime('first day of next month'))->format('F');
```

The reason why you see this problem is when adding time to a date at the end of the month you run into issues with months having fewer than 31 days. This can cause you to skip a month. The best bet is to always start your date math at the beginning of the month before adding time to it or just relative formats as demonstrated above.

PHP 5.3:

```
$nextMonth = new DateTime('first day of next month');
echo $nextMonth->format('F');
```

Comment: -> Thanks, how do I assign it to a variable? From some reason this gives me an error: `$nextmonth = (new DateTime('first day of next month'))->format('F'); `

Comment: Having said that it also gives me an error when I echo it. I have PHP 5.3

Comment: @Metzed Updated to work with PHP 5.3. Just had to break it down to two lines.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I managed to work that out just before you sent your answer :) - thanks a lot for your help!